# Submit in a fetch mode collapsed rows

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this datatable:

```
 <p:dataTable id="necesidades"
         value="#{registrarAccionDosBean.accionDos.necesidadesConTema}"
         rendered="#{not empty registrarAccionDosBean.accionDos.necesidadesConTema}"
         var="necesidad"
         rowKey="#{necesidad.idNecesidad}">
    <p:column style="width:16px">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>
    <p:rowExpansion>
        <h:panelGroup id="grupoTema">
            <h:panelGroup id="edicion" rendered="#{necesidad.tema.idTema ne null}">
              <p:row>
                <p:column >
                   <h:outputLabel value="#{etiq.lbl_comunes_requerido} #{etiq.etiqueta_checkbox_transparenciasFocalizadas}" styleClass="textoAcciones"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column >
                    <!-- Nested data table -->
                    <p:dataTable id="transparenciasInplace"
                         var="transparencias" 
                         value="#{registrarAccionDosBean.transparenciasFocalizadas}"
                         selection="#{necesidad.tema.transparenciasFocalizadas}"
                         rowKey="#{transparencias.idTf}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Objetives
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{transparencias.descripcion}" styleClass="textoAccionesSmall"/>        
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                 </p:column>
              </p:row>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

I have n rows collapsed with information inside of each of them, this information was persisted in different times and days, so I need to save some information plus the n rows as a whole, the problem is that the rows are collapsed when is show on screen and I want to be in that way because a can have a lot rows on screen and if I show them expanded it will be hard to read, but when I send it through a command button the table inside my collapsed row are setting null, I need to expand each of them in order to properly send all the information.

So I want to send the information collapsed but in some way force to fetch the information inside of each of them

I am getting the information from the database right, because there I just fetch my query and get the information right, so my problem is on my jsf page I think